# Dates format in Message's chat.db

Tags: macos, messages, database

I'm working on improving my [iMessages backup-script](https://github.com/kyro38/MiscStuff/blob/master/OSXStuff/iMessageBackup.sh). `/Users/Kyro/Library/Messages/chat.db` has a table `message` with all the messages an some dates.

Any idea what's the date format ? I first thought of a timestamp (I have for example `408978598`) but `date -r 408978598` return a date in 1982.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well using [coreUtils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) date :

I found what I was looking for :

```
$gdate -ud "2001-01-01 + 408978598 seconds" 
Tue Dec 17 13:09:58 UTC 2013
```

It's a timestamp with base date January 1st, 2001.

Comment: To see it in your default local timezone, omit the `-u` option and add the UTC timezone indicator to the date string:  `$ gdate -d "2001-01-01Z + 408978598 seconds"`

Answer (score 14):

I found that as of High Sierra, I needed to use a different date transformation. The 8 extra 0's on the date field versus the date_read field was the clue:

```
datetime(message.date/1000000000 + strftime("%s", "2001-01-01") ,"unixepoch","localtime")
```

Comment: Yes, it is now a nanosecond field.

Comment: As of 2018, this answer works as expected.

Comment: As of 2019, this answer works as expected

Comment: As of 2020, this answer works as expected.

Comment: As of 2021, this answer works as expected.  

Comment: As of 2022, this answer works as expected.

Comment: As of 2023, this answer works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to @Matthieu's helpful answer, here's how to convert it within SQLLite:

```
datetime(date + strftime('%s','2001-01-01'), 'unixepoch')
```

For example:

```
select
  is_from_me,
  datetime(date + strftime('%s','2001-01-01'), 'unixepoch') as date_utc,
  text
from message;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, all dates have the year -1400

Answer (score 0):

In the script you are referring to, you can achieve timestamping like so: datetime(date + strftime('%s', '2001-01-01 00:00:00'), 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as date from message--to get in in local time if that's what you are looking for.